# Is there a more idiomatic way to create a builder function property in TypeScript/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've created a function typed property in a component to handle construction of objects consistently. For some reason I keep thinking there's a cleaner way to do this in TypeScript and can't seem to find anything that really confirms my suspicion. What is an alternative way to doing the following?

```
buildDateRangeItem = (buildStartDate: Date, buildEndDate: Date, dateModeId: number,
    displayName: string,
    previousItem?: DateRangeItem,
    formatExpression?: itemFormatExpression
    ): DateRangeItem => {
      const item = {
        displayName: undefined,
        startDate: buildStartDate,
        endDate: buildEndDate,
        dateModeId: dateModeId,
        previous: previousItem
      }

      item.displayName = formatExpression ? formatExpression(item) : displayName;

      return item;
    }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the problem with what you have now.  You can possibly refactor out the "maybe format this" to avoid declaring an `item` but I can't imagine you'll get something nicer looking than what you have.  Could you define your `itemFormatExpression` and `DateRangeItems` types to make this a [mcve] so I can maybe make a suggestion?  If `itemFormatExpression` can ever read the `displayName` property of the item it processes, you might have trouble with your definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "*a function typed property in a component*"? And can you show us how that `buildDateRangeItem` function is called? We might be able to help you simplify then.